# Is there a term for vulnerabilities the need 'help' from target vs vulnerabilities that can be exploited with no actions from the target?

Tags: terminology

I'm making a guideline for a bug bounty program and want to distinguish between bugs that require some kind of action on the target's behalf (eg clicking a suspicious link), vs vulnerabilities that can be exploited without any actions from the user (eg, SQL injection that gives you users' credentials).

I don't necessarily mean phishing, just any vulnerability depending on action from the user rather than one that can be done 'cold', if that makes sense.

Does such terminology already exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would describe such vulnerability as needing *user interaction*.

This is also the term [used by CVSS](https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln-metrics/cvss/v3-calculator) to describe it,